# CSS, HTML tag issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue in

```
<ul class='nav'>            
        <li>
          <a class='' href='index.html'> Home </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS code for this

```
 .topbar div>ul a,  .nav a
  {display:block;float:none;outline: 0;padding:8px 6px 6px;line-height:12px;text-    decoration:none;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;}
```

I just want these properties with Home and DropDown buttons only, I don't want to have these for my tab buttons i.e. Action, Another Actions buttons. But whenever I try to edit this, the whole thing get messed up.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    <li>
      <a class='dropdown-toggle' href='index.html'> Home </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </li>
    </ul>


.dropdown-toggle
{
    display:block;
    float:none;outline: 0;
    padding:8px 6px 6px;
    line-height:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your html looks wrong. Double `<li>` at one point.

But here is for the CSS:

```
a{
    outline: 0;
}
ul.nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:8px 6px 6px;
    line-height:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:5px;
}
ul.nav ul a{
    padding:8px 6px 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the selector to:
.topbar div>ul li.dropdown > a,  .nav a